# ¿Cómo evitar valores duplicados en una consulta con Joins en la misma tabla?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy intentando realizar un reporte de ventas de productos por mes en *PostgreSQL*, tengo dos tablas **documentoCab** y **documproductodet**.

En la tabla **documentoCab** tengo:

```
id          estado
--------------------
1            TRUE
```

En la tabla **documproductodet** tengo:

```
id     iddocumentocab      fecha
------------------------------------
1         1              21/01/2017 
2         1              12/01/2017
3         1              07/01/2017
4         1              07/02/2017
5         1              07/03/2017
```

Lo que pretendo conseguir es obtener los datos como muestro a continuación:

```
Ene      Feb      Mar
----------------------
 1        4        5
 2       NULL    NULL
 3       NULL    NULL
```

Estoy utilizando la siguiente consulta *SQL*:

```
SELECT 
        dpdEne.id Ene,
        dpdFeb.id Feb,
        dpdMar.id Mar

from documentocab dc

left join documproductodet dpdEne on dpdEne.iddocumentocab = dc.id and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dpdEne.fecha)= 1 
left join documproductodet dpdFeb on dpdFeb.iddocumentocab = dc.id and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dpdFeb.fecha)= 2 
left join documproductodet dpdMar on dpdMar.iddocumentocab = dc.id and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dpdMar.fecha)= 3
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
Ene      Feb      Mar
----------------------
 1        4        5
 2        4        5
 3        4        5
```

La idea es que aparezca el valor NULL y no los valores repetidos.

Comment: Además de lo que indica @sstan en su comentario, quisiera agregar que te recomiendo actualizar tu pregunta proporcionando mas datos de prueba; por ejemplo, ¿qué información tiene la tabla **documentoCab**?

Comment: Sí, utilizo PostgreSQL, y en realidad me interesan los 12 meses del año, pero puse enero, febrero y marzo para resumir. Mencioné el **Group By** porque la idea final era agrupar por producto, pero lo que necesito antes es obtener los datos como los muestro en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien raro la forma de presentar los datos que pides, y no entiendo bien el propósito de la tabla `documentoCab`. Pero sí es posible hacer lo que pides usando la función ventana `ROW_NUMBER()` para determinar en qué fila debe presentarse un registro en particular, combinado con agregaciones condicionales para la presentación por mes:

```
with cte as (
  select dp.id,
         extract(month from dp.fecha) as month_id,
         row_number() over (
           partition by extract(month from dp.fecha)
           order by dp.id) as seq
    from documentoCab dc
    join documproductodet dp
      on dp.iddocumentocab = dc.id)
select max(case when month_id = 1 then id end) as Ene,
       max(case when month_id = 2 then id end) as Feb,
       max(case when month_id = 3 then id end) as Mar
  from cte
 group by seq
 order by seq
```

Resultado:

```
Ene      Feb      Mar
----------------------
 1        4        5
 2       NULL    NULL
 3       NULL    NULL
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/BCAJ76016)</kbd>

Como puedes ver, no hay necesidad de hacer un join para cada mes cómo lo estabas intentando. Y es muy fácil agregarle los demás meses:

```
with cte as (
  select dp.id,
         extract(month from dp.fecha) as month_id,
         row_number() over (
           partition by extract(month from dp.fecha)
           order by dp.id) as seq
    from documentoCab dc
    join documproductodet dp
      on dp.iddocumentocab = dc.id)
select max(case when month_id = 1 then id end) as Ene,
       max(case when month_id = 2 then id end) as Feb,
       max(case when month_id = 3 then id end) as Mar,
       max(case when month_id = 4 then id end) as Abr,
       max(case when month_id = 5 then id end) as May,
       max(case when month_id = 6 then id end) as Jun,
       max(case when month_id = 7 then id end) as Jul,
       max(case when month_id = 8 then id end) as Ago,
       max(case when month_id = 9 then id end) as Sep,
       max(case when month_id = 10 then id end) as Oct,
       max(case when month_id = 11 then id end) as Nov,
       max(case when month_id = 12 then id end) as Dic
  from cte
 group by seq
 order by seq
```

Comment: Gracias!!   Y bueno la razón por la que los pedía así era porque existe una tabla más llamada producto que se relaciona con **documproductodet**  y necesitaba sumar las cantidades vendidas de cada producto por mes y con la forma que lo tenía yo se repetían los valores.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas hacer es conseguir la cantidad de ventas que has realizado por cada mes. Ejecuta la siguiente consulta en PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Cantidad Vendida",   
    CASE date_part('month'::text, fecha)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Enero'::text
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Febrero'::text
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Marzo'::text
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril'::text
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Mayo'::text
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Junio'::text
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Julio'::text
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto'::text
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Septiembre'::text
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'::text
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'::text
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembre'::text
        ELSE NULL::text
    END AS mes From documproductodet dc
    WHERE date_part('year'::text, fecha) = 2017::double precision
    GROUP BY 
    CASE date_part('month'::text, fecha)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Enero'::text
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Febrero'::text
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Marzo'::text
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril'::text
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Mayo'::text
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Junio'::text
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Julio'::text
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto'::text
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Septiembre'::text
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'::text
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'::text
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembre'::text
        ELSE NULL::text
    END, date_part('year'::text, fecha)::integer
```

El resultado que lanza la consulta es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe destacar que en dicha consulta ya he agregado a todos los meses del año, de manera a que puedan ser de utilidad.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con

```
Select Distinct ...
```

Distinct se usa para no mostrar valores duplicados en una consulta y se escribe directamente después del SELECT.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, pero usando DISTINCT  me arroja los mismos resultados, aun probando con el SELECT DISTINCT ON... no obtengo el resultado esperado.